# PHP (class.upload.php): Resize picture depending on Width and Height

Tags: php, resize-image

I'm using class class.upload.php to resize and upload images.
My images need to be exact 770x400.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1) upload image - DONE

2) resize image to width 770px or height 400px

3) cut image to 770x400 using visual cutter (Jcrop Image) - DONE

I'm struggling now with 2nd point as don't know how to recognize image proportion.

Example:
If image has width 2156px and height 777px than need to be resized to the height: 400px as this will give 1100x400

If image has width 777px and height 2156px than need to be resized to the width: 770px as this will give 770x2137

How to recognize image proportion?

To resize to the width I'm using class.upload.php parameters:

```
$handle->image_resize = true;
$handle->image_ratio_y = true;
$handle->image_x = 770;
```

To resize to height I'm using:

```
$handle->image_resize = true;
$handle->image_ratio_x = true;
$handle->image_y = 400;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think I found answer myself.

```
list($read_w, $read_h, $type, $attr)= getimagesize($_FILES['file']);
$oryginalimage_ratio=$read_w/$read_h;
$desiredimage_ratio=770/400;

if($oryginalimage_ratio>$desiredimage_ratio){
  $handle->image_resize = true;
  $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
  $handle->image_x = 770; 
}else{
  $handle->image_resize = true;
  $handle->image_ratio_x = true;
  $handle->image_y = 400; 
}
```